# How to solve ENOENT error for my json-server?

Tags: javascript, json, database, vue.js, json-server

I am getting this error below.

```
PS C:\Users\Tan Shi Yu\Github\shopaway> npx json-server --watch data/db.json

  \{^_^}/ hi!

  Loading data/db.json
  Oops, data/db.json doesn't seem to exist
  Creating data/db.json with some default data

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'data/db.json'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:498:3)
    at Object.writeFileSync (fs.js:1524:35)
    at C:\Users\Tan Shi Yu\Github\shopaway\node_modules\json-server\lib\cli\utils\load.js:44:12
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\Tan Shi Yu\Github\shopaway\node_modules\json-server\lib\cli\utils\load.js:38:10)
    at start (C:\Users\Tan Shi Yu\Github\shopaway\node_modules\json-server\lib\cli\run.js:112:12)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\Tan Shi Yu\Github\shopaway\node_modules\json-server\lib\cli\run.js:149:3)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\Tan Shi Yu\Github\shopaway\node_modules\json-server\lib\cli\index.js:86:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Tan Shi Yu\Github\shopaway\node_modules\json-server\lib\cli\bin.js:6:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1068:30) {
  errno: -4058,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: 'data/db.json'
}
```

However, I believe my file is installed in the right location as seen here.
[image]

May I know if I am doing something wrong? Thanks!

Comment: well, that doesnt guarantee that data/db.sjon is in the right place after running npx/deployment. please check if that is also true.

Comment: also, the file to watch that you're specifying at the command line is not located at src, as one can see the command line path is C:\Users\Tan Shi Yu\Github\shopaway, which is not  the same as C:\Users\Tan Shi Yu\Github\shopaway\src - maybe that is an issue as well

Comment: Hello, thanks for the comment. I think I managed to solve this in the end by placing src in front of my data/db.json file.